# Recreating a ManipulationStarting event programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, touch, draggable

I have a canvas.  Within this canvas (let's say off to the right) I have a StackPanel, wrapped in a ScrollViewer, containing images.  I would like the user to be able to grab an image from the StackPanel and drag it wherever they will within the Canvas.

I can remove the selected image from the StackPanel and add it to the Canvas in the exact same spot visually, but this ends the manipulation event, causing the user to have to grab the image again in order to continue moving it. I am attempting to get around this by attempting to create a new ManipulationStarting event, but I am having trouble getting it right.  My code is as follows...

```
var element = e.Source as System.Windows.Controls.Image;
var sp = element.Parent as StackPanel;

if (sp != null)
{
    GeneralTransform transform = element.TransformToAncestor(this);
    System.Windows.Point TouchEndPoint = transform.Transform(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0));

    Canvas.SetTop(element, TouchEndPoint.Y);
    Canvas.SetLeft(element, TouchEndPoint.X);
    Grid.SetZIndex(element, 20);
    //element.Tag = "Image on Canvas";
    element.Opacity = 1;

    sp.Children.Remove(element);
    _anvas.Children.Add(element);

    var args = new RoutedEventArgs(System.Windows.Controls.Image.ManipulationStartingEvent, element);

    element.RaiseEvent(args);
}
else
{
    e.ManipulationContainer = _canvas;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you are trying to implement Drag&Drop between stack panel and canvas.

First of all I recommend Bea Stollnitz's [great article](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/488#.VNCGoGiUcRo) on Drag&Drop.

In addition I propose you to put an ItemsControl instead of StackPanel as a drag source and make Canvas an ItemsPanel of ListBox. That way you will grad and drop between StackPanel and Canvas visually, while logically it will be between ItemsControl and ListBox.

There is an [example](http://wpf.2000things.com/2014/01/31/999-using-a-canvas-as-the-items-panel-for-a-listbox/) of ListBox with Canvas as ItemsPanel.